# read.table for txt file will give incomplete data

Tags: r, read.table

I find read.table() to import a very large txt file (3GB), then it runs without any message/warning/error. But the imported data is incomplete. Why does this happen?

R users, please be aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the alternative package

```
library(data.table)
myData <- fread("myData.txt")
```

The above method does not have the issue.